# 401 UNAUTHORIZED error with jquery get method with Tastypie api

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, django, tastypie

As of now I am not using authentication for Tastypie but I am able to see content, when I go to url in browser.

```
http://localhost:8000/live/api/update/?format=json
```

but I am trying to get this data in the page via an jquery ajax call,

```
$.post('/live/api/update/?format=json',
            {type:'GET',dataType: "json", processData:  false,
  contentType: "application/json",userid:$('#index').val()},function(devicelist){       
    .....       
    }
```

In browser firebug console, I m seeing a 401

Note : from Haris's Answer, I was able to solve the issue, but I want why it works

when I use

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: data, success: success, dataType: dataType });
```

it is working(Status:202) whereas when I use

```
  $.post('/live/api/update/?format=json',
                {type:'GET',dataType: "json", processData:  false,
      contentType: "application/json",userid:$('#index').val()},function(devicelist){       
        .....       
        }
```

this is not working.Actually I shifted my PHP code to Django, when I used PHP the above code used to work with 401 error

There is no Authentication in tastypie api code

## api.py

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from models import Update
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer
import urlparse

class urlencodeSerializer(Serializer):
    formats = ['json', 'jsonp', 'xml', 'yaml', 'html', 'plist', 'urlencode']
    ....


class UpdateResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta : 
        
        queryset = Update.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'update'
        filtering = {'imei' : ALL }
        #authentication = DjangoCookieBasicAuthentication()
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer() # IMPORTANT 
        allowed_methods = ['get','post']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're sending a $.POST request with jquery, yet you're trying to change the type to a GET. Use .ajax if you want to add custom options to the ajax request.